# How to put Button in SpriteKit with Swift code using Xcode 7?

Tags: swift, button, xcode7

I tried to make a game on Xcode 7 Beta, I almost finished it but the problem is I don't know how to put buttons with Swift code, I tried to put them on Main.storyboard but they don't arrange very well. some of them become bigger and some smaller etc... So I want to know how to put these buttons with code as in picture below. Blue button first from the left is Leaderboard, then Facebook share, twitter share, and another default button (maybe it will be Remove Ads)

[image]

Then I tried to use some code:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    
    
    leaderboard()
    facebookShare()
    twitterShare()
}




func leaderboard() {
   let myNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "buttonLeaderboard")
    myNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) *0.40, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) * 0.25)
    self.addChild(myNode)
}


func facebookShare() {
    let facebookShareNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "buttonFacebookShare")
    facebookShareNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) *0.60, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) * 0.25)
    self.addChild(facebookShareNode)
}


func twitterShare() {
    let twitterShareNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "buttonTwitterShare")
    twitterShareNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) *0.80, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) * 0.25)
    self.addChild(twitterShareNode)
}
```

But it finds 3 errors on these codes

> "myNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) *0.40, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) * 0.25)"
>
> "facebookShareNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) *0.60, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) * 0.25)"
>
> "twitterShareNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) *0.80, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) * 0.25)"

Errors say "Expected ',' separator", but when I do as errors say it find again another 3 errors and this time they say "'*' is not a prefix unary operator", What to do in this case ? Can someone help me ?

Comment: You don't need to use `CGPointMake` and `CGRectGetMaxX`, etc. in Swift, you can just use the initializer `CGPoint(x: , y: )` and computed property `frame.maxX`. The `self.` is also unnecessary in most contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the compiler error you'd basically just need to add a space after the `*`, but it's better to use the more Swift-like style:

```
myNode.position = CGPoint(x: frame.maxX * 0.4, y: frame.maxY * 0.25)
```

As for the positions, well, adjust the `x` coordinates. For the sizes easiest would be to provide the images in equal sizes so you don't have to scale them?

Comment: If we use this code, and if we change iPhone simulator the buttons will be bad arranged ! So this is not right code.

Comment: @EminEmini I answered the question of how to fix the compiler error, and the question of how to make them the same size. As for the arrangement, you are of course free to arrange them however you like; I don't have the images, or your app, and much less do I know how you want them arranged. Adjust the x and y coordinates to get a good layout…

Comment: I just want the space between buttons to be in all iPhones same, with this code when I change simulator space of buttons become smaller (bigger in bigger simulators) and they aren't arrange from the center in some simulators the 1st button starts from center, in some from right, in some normaly as I want (as in photo, check above photo in question). This will solve everything !
Anyway thanks for Your contribute.

Comment: @EminEmini Well, presumably `frame.maxX` and `frame.maxY` will differ based on the device, and your `x` and `y` are fractions of those, so they will also differ. For example, if `maxX == 1000` then you have `1000 * 0.4` and `1000 * 0.6` for `400` and `600` — a difference of `200` — but if `maxX == 500` then you have `200` and `300`, difference of `100`, so the spacing changes… So clearly it's not a good idea to set `x` this way.

Comment: @EminEmini The simplest fix for this would be to just hard-code the coordinates (e.g., `x: 100` for the first one, `x: 100 + button_width + button_spacing` for the second one, `x: 100 + button_width * 2 + button_spacing * 2` for the third one, etc). Once you got that working, change (only) the `100` to something depending on the screen size…

Comment: It found errors "Cannot find an initializer for type 'CGPoint' that accepts an argument list of type '(x: Int, y: CGFloat)’" ,(I'm so sorry for many questions but I'm beginner and I'm teenager, and In my country are just about 20 iOS Developers all of them live outside my country and I can't contact them)

Comment: @EminEmini Both `x` and `y` must be of type `CGFloat`. If you added `button_width` and `button_height` make sure they are `CGFloat`, e.g., `let buttonWidth: CGFloat = 50`. Or you can put `CGFloat(…)` around the argument, i.e., `CGPoint(x: CGFloat(100 + …), y: CGFloat(…))` Meanwhile I recommend reading Apple's free eBook on Swift and trying things out in the Playground while you read.

Comment: myNode.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5), I thought to use something like this to make them in center, because they move on left when I change simulator, but it's not working so I know something is missing. Ya I take some courses online and it's going good I made two simple apps and are available on App Store (they was available 2nd week from 1st lecture) but SpriteKit is so hard.

Comment: What You think about this last problem ?

Comment: @EminEmini I lost track of where you're at, I suggest asking a new question with your updated code and problem.

Comment: Anyway I will ask another question about this thanks my friends, thanks for Your time. :)